# XML deserialize brings back empty list

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, game-development

I have a dictionary of abilityobjects <id, abilityObj> that I'm trying to serialize in XML. Because you can't XML Serialize a dictionary, I change it into a list on serialization

```
public class BattleSerializable : TyrantSerializable
{
    [XmlIgnoreAttribute]
    [NonSerialized]
    [DoNotSerialize]
    public Dictionary<int, AbilityObjectSerializable> battleObjects;
    
    public List<AbilityObjectSerializable> serializedBattleObjects
    {
        get
        {
            if (battleObjects == null)
            {
                battleObjects = new Dictionary<int, AbilityObjectSerializable>();
            }

            return battleObjects.Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
        }
        set
        {
            battleObjects = value.ToDictionary(x => x.entityId, x => x);
        }
    }
```

It serializes correctly. I.e. the XML that gets saved makes sense

```
<BattleSerializable>
    ...
    <serializedBattleObjects>
      <AbilityObjectSerializable xmlns:d3p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" d3p1:type="FireballObject">
         <hexDirection>southeast</hexDirection>
         <gridX>0</gridX>
         <gridZ>7</gridZ>
         <entityId>3</entityId>
         <lastAnimation>STATUE</lastAnimation>
         <timer>0</timer>
         <abilityPos>2</abilityPos>
         <abilityType>FIREBALL</abilityType>
         <health>100</health>
         <tilesPerTurn>2</tilesPerTurn>
         <jump>1</jump>
         <fall>99</fall>
         <damage>5</damage>
         <lineTraversed>
            <xDisplace>1</xDisplace>
            <zDisplace>-2</zDisplace>
            <endTileFacing>east</endTileFacing>
         </lineTraversed>
         <moveDirection>
            <xDisplace>1</xDisplace>
            <zDisplace>-2</zDisplace>
            <endTileFacing>east</endTileFacing>
         </moveDirection>
      </AbilityObjectSerializable>
    </serializedBattleObjects>
</BattleSerializable>
```

But when I try to then -load- this XML and turn it into actual C# objects, this list comes in empty for some reason, causing the app to blow up.

What am I missing? All the other lists in this class serialize/deserialize correctly.

My load code:

```
public BattleSerializable Load(string path)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BattleSerializable));
    try
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(stream);
            string xmlString = xmlDoc.InnerXml;
            BattleSerializable bs = (BattleSerializable)this.LoadFromXML(xmlString);
            return bs;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new SettingLoadException("Settings failed validation");
    }
}
```

Comment: The best way of debugging is to add data to the classes and serialize.  The compare the serialized xml to the actual xml you are trying to import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way a lot of serializers work is by calling `Add` on a list, only actually assigning anything back to the setter if *the serializer created the list* (perhaps because it was `null`, or fixed size such as an array). So imagine the serializer doing:

```cs
var list = obj.SomeProperty;
while (moreOfTheSame)
   list.Add(ReadOneOfThose());
```

It *never calls the setter*, so any logic in there: irrelevant. You'll probably need a custom list type here, or perhaps more simply: have a nice simple POCO/DTO model that *just* maps to the serialization shape with no fun logic, and project between this model and your domain model *separately* to serialization.

Comment: Perfect. Helped me understand what was going on. Making a custom dictionary worked